# date conversion SQL-VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am getting data from SQL and pasting it to an excel sheet through VBA. The data comes in format

hh:mm:ss and I want excel to realize this is a time variable but that is not the case. Even if I select the pasted area and change format to any time format it doesn't seem to be working. It only works if I manually select a cell modify it slightly and click enter (or F2+enter for each cell) then it moves to a time format is there a way to fix this or is someone familiar with this issue?

Comment: Do you have an example of the Timestamp that is being pasted?

Comment: How is the column stored in SQL - string or Datetime ?

Comment: it is a date format at SQL I am doing convert(varchar(8), start_time, 108) as starttime, to get the hh:mm:ss format

Comment: so one of these cell say 21:10:30. Excel is keeping this value as is. if I click press F2 and enter it changes to the time format say 9:10:30 PM or any format I select for the cell

Comment: Its varchar(8) hence is the issue. Convert it again to datetime. It will solve your problem.

Comment: hmm but wouldn't that make the data still an entire date format. I want the data to be in hh:mm:dd format without the yyyy/mm/dd included in

Comment: Get start_time column as its is and then format the column as hh:mm:dd

Comment: Thanks for the help Santosh. I am using the data to create graphs so it won't work as dates make things bad. is there a way to get the only hh:mm:ss from the datetime variable as a time variable?

Comment: Try this Convert(Time(0),start_time,0)

Answer (score -1):

How exactly are you getting this data *into* excel?

You would not happen to have Manual Calculation on would you?  Excel will parse hh:mm:ss into a datetime, but it sounds like it is not recalculating after however you import this data.

Comment: I checked that it says that it is set to automatic. Excel just hating on me I guess.

Comment: Any particular reason this was downvoted? I'm asking questions to help troubleshoot.